# I'm trying to make a simple calculator and having problem performing second operation

Tags: javascript

It works fine until you press an operator key for a second time and it just uses the second value from the first operation.
for example if I do (8-1 = 7), then if I multiply  it by 2 instead of being 14 it will do(1*2= 2) using the second value from the first operation as the first value.

I have tried different solutions and it seems like a simple problem but for some reason nothing works.

```
   html code:
 <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Calculator||ONLINE</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
<div class="main-div">
  <div class="calc-container">
    <div class="display">
      <div class="disIn" id="display-input"></div>
      <div class="disOut" id="display-output"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- btns-->
    <div class="btn">
      <button data-action="clear" id="ac">AC</button>
      <button data-action="delete" id="del">DEL</button>
      <button class="key--operator" data-action="divide" id="divide">
        ÷
      </button>
      <button class="btn-num" id="1">1</button>
      <button class="btn-num" id="2">2</button>
      <button class="btn-num" id="3">3</button>
      <button class="key--operator" data-action="add" id="add">+</button>
      <button class="btn-num" id="4">4</button>
      <button class="btn-num" id="5">5</button>
      <button class="btn-num" id="6">6</button>
      <button class="key--operator" data-action="subtract" id="minus">
        -
      </button>
      <button class="btn-num" id="7">7</button>
      <button class="btn-num" id="8">8</button>
      <button class="btn-num" id="9">9</button>
      <button class="key--operator" data-action="multiply" id="times">
        ×
      </button>
      <button class="btn-num" id="0">0</button>
      <button class="key--operator" data-action="decimal" id="decimal">
        .
      </button>
      <button class="key--equal" data-action="equal" id="equal">=</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
     <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>

      javascript code:  
          const calculator = document.querySelector('.calc-container');
          const keys = calculator.querySelector('.btn');
          const display = document.querySelector('.display')
          const calcDisplayIn = document.querySelector('#display-input');
         const calcDisplayOut = document.querySelector('#display-output');
        /* const disIn = document.querySelector('.disIn');
        const disOut = document.querySelector('.disOut') */;

          keys.addEventListener('click',e => {
            if(e.target.matches('button')){
                const key = e.target
                const action = key.dataset.action;
                const keyContent = key.textContent;
               const numDisplayed = calcDisplayIn.textContent;
              const outPutDisplay =  calcDisplayOut.textContent;
               Array.from(key.parentNode.children)
                  .forEach(k => k.classList.remove('identify'))
                 if (!action) {
                      const previousKeyType = calculator.dataset.previousKeyType
                        if (numDisplayed === '0' || previousKeyType === 'operator') {
                         calcDisplayIn.textContent = keyContent
                       }   else {
                         calcDisplayIn.textContent = numDisplayed + keyContent;
                            }
                       }
                    if(action === 'decimal'){
                        if (!numDisplayed.includes('.')) {
                                calcDisplayIn.textContent = numDisplayed + '.'
                          }else if(previousKeyType === 'operator') {
                                  calcDisplayIn.textContent = '0.'
                              }
        
                calculator.dataset.previousKeyType = 'decimal'
                      }if(action === 'add'){
                    calcDisplayIn.textContent = numDisplayed + '+'
                      }if(action === 'subtract'){
                        calcDisplayIn.textContent = numDisplayed + '-'
                      }if(action === 'multiply'){
                            calcDisplayIn.textContent = numDisplayed + '×'
                     }if(action === 'divide'){
        calcDisplayIn.textContent = numDisplayed + '÷'
    }if(action === 'clear'){
  calcDisplayIn.textContent = '';
  calcDisplayOut.textContent = '';
    }if(action === 'delete'){
      calcDisplayIn.textContent =calcDisplayIn.textContent.slice(0,length -1)
      }
      if (
        action === 'add' ||
        action === 'subtract' ||
        action === 'multiply' ||
        action === 'divide'
      ) {   const firstValue = calculator.dataset.firstValue
        const operator = calculator.dataset.operator
        const secondValue = numDisplayed;
        if(firstValue && operator){
          calcDisplayOut.textContent = calculate(firstValue,operator,secondValue);
        }
      key.classList.add('identify')
       calculator.dataset.firstValue = numDisplayed;
         calculator.dataset.previousKeyType = 'operator';
         calculator.dataset.operator = action;

      }
      
      function calculate(n1,operator,n2){
        let result = '';
     
        if (operator === 'add') {
            result = parseFloat(n1) + parseFloat(n2)
          } else if (operator === 'subtract') {
            result = parseFloat(n1) - parseFloat(n2)
          } else if (operator === 'multiply') {
            result = parseFloat(n1) * parseFloat(n2)
          } else if (operator === 'divide') {
            result = parseFloat(n1) / parseFloat(n2)
          }
       
         
          return result;
      }
   
      const firstValue = calculator.dataset.firstValue
      const operator = calculator.dataset.operator
      const secondValue = numDisplayed;
      if(action === 'equal'){
        calcDisplayOut.textContent = calculate(firstValue, operator, secondValue)
         } 

   }
})
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to add a [mre]? You can read more about creating a mre here: [ask].

Comment: needs a refactor, use an array of objects which contain (number, action, result) then you can run over the array to calculate, undo a sum and have running tally etc. doing it all on the dom without working vars is bound to have issues

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thanks i will try that ,but if its not too much to ask for  could you maybe re-write the part of the code so I can get an idea or just see what should be done

Comment: too much bloat in vanilla js, id use vue like https://playcode.io/784910/

Comment: @LawrenceCherone i appreciate the help but  im still a beginner and have never worked with vue before

Comment: @0stone0 i didnt remove anything incase the problem is somewhere in the code where i didnt realise